# Override responsive-image-formatter for given image field of a content type

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to override the `responsive-image-formatter.html.twig` template.

I copied it into themes/custom/mytheme/templates/field folder and renamed it to `responsive-image-formatter--node--gallery--field-picture.html.twig` as I wanted to override it only for the `field-picture` image field of the `gallery` content type.

I followed this way, because this is how I could overwrite the `image-formatter.html.twig` template. I thought the behavior is same.

I cleaned the cache, but it doesn't work. The system still uses the core template instead.

Any idea or hints?